# apache solr sorting by price and sale_price

Tags: sorting, solr

I have the case to show product data with ascending sorting.
Let's say i have this data :

```
{
    "product_name":"Boyfriend 74 series",
    "product_price":489900},
  {
    "product_name":"Skinny 70 Series",
    "product_price":499900},
  {
    "product_name":"Faran Pant",
    "product_sale_price":490000,
    "product_price":549000},
  {
    "product_name":"Dakota Ripped Jeans",
    "product_sale_price":98000,
    "product_price":559000
  }
```

Could SOLR sorting the data if the data has product_sale_price and product_sale_price less then product_price, so product_sale_price position should be before product_price?

This is what i want :

```
      {
        "product_name":"Dakota Ripped Jeans",
        "product_sale_price":98000,
        "product_price":559000
      }
      {  
        "product_name":"Boyfriend 74 series",
        "product_price":489900},          
      {
        "product_name":"Faran Pant",
        "product_sale_price":490000,
        "product_price":549000
      },
      {
        "product_name":"Skinny 70 Series",
        "product_price":499900
      },
```

Comment: sale price shown both case have a miss match for Faran Pant and Dakota Ripped...

Comment: what do you mean miss match?

Comment: in the sample data it show a sale price and in the expected result it show different sales price...

Comment: i have edit my expected result,sorry for miss match

Comment: did you tried below answer...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sub function

&sort=sub(product_price,product_sale_price)desc

if you want try more on it ...check on the other available functions

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery

Comment: i have tried this answer and the result still not as my expected result.